# How to get a SubString of variable using stencil templating tool for swift

Tags: templating, swift-stencil

I'm using the stencil template language tool for swift found here:
https://github.com/stencilproject/Stencil

Using master branch.

**The Problem**

given the following `.json` file

```
{
  "xcassets" : "dev Sources test1"
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve the first word delimited by `" "` which is "dev".

**What I've Tried**

The latest version of Stencil has the [Split Function](https://stencil.fuller.li/en/latest/builtins.html#split). But the problem is I can't figure out how to access the first element in the resulting array, and it's not in the [documentation](https://stencil.fuller.li/en/latest/) either.

I've tried the following in the stencil file:

```
{{xcassets|split:" "[0]}}

{{{{xcassets|split:" "}}[0]}}

{{xcassets|split:" ".first}}

{{xcassets|split:" "}}.first}}

{{xcassets|split:" "|[0]}}

{{xcassets|split:" "|.first}}

{{xcassets|split:" "|first}}
```

None of which worked.

**What I'm trying to avoid**

I know I can do it this way, but there must be a better way.

```
{% for element in xcassets|split:" " %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        {{ element }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Anyone have suggestions for a better tool?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is the only way:

```
{% for element in xcassets|split:" " %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        {{ element }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: For better readability put this inside a {% macro %}